# AVFoundation : AVCaptureSession Freeze

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession

> 2018-01-05 09:33:51.242999-0500 XXXXXXX[987:169984] Capture session
>   runtime error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The
>   operation could not be completed"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16811),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1c465ddf0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-16811 "(null)"}}

I get above code after taking about 10 RAW photos in a row.  Camera feed would start getting glitchy and completely would come to a freeze after few more photos.

No other error messages or no memory leaks visible though Instruments.

This doesn't happen with JPEG or any other image formats. Setting up RAW:

```
let newPhotoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(rawPixelFormatType: OSType(self.photoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!),
                                              processedFormat: [((kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString) as String): NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)])
newPhotoSettings.previewPhotoFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: newPhotoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes[0]]

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    newPhotoSettings.embeddedThumbnailPhotoFormat =  [AVVideoCodecKey: newPhotoSettings.availableEmbeddedThumbnailPhotoCodecTypes[0]]
}
newPhotoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
newPhotoSettings.flashMode = self.flashMode
newPhotoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = false
newPhotoSettings.livePhotoMovieFileURL = nil
self.photoOutput.photoSettingsForSceneMonitoring = newPhotoSettings

self.photoOutput.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([newPhotoSettings], completionHandler: nil)
```